# How does current flow in this temperature protection circuit?

Tags: voltage-divider, temperature, thermistor

Reading through the [data sheet](https://image.dfrobot.com/image/data/DFR0208/TP4056.pdf) for a TP4056 Li-ion battery charger, I found the diagram of a typical application. I'm trying to fathom how the temperature protection circuit functions. I've found this [simple example](https://www.doeeet.com/content/eee-components/passives/how-to-use-temperature-protection-devices-ntc-thermistors/) of a temperature protection circuit that's implemented as a [voltage divider](https://www.circuitbasics.com/what-is-a-voltage-divider/) using one regular resistor and one thermistor, but I don't think that's how it works.

The data sheet says the charging current to the battery will be cut off when the voltage across the IC's TEMP pin drops below 45%, or rises above 80% of the input voltage. I can only imagine that as the NTC thermistor heats up, it offers less resistance and allows more current to flow through TEMP, who's resistance is constant so the voltage across it increases. Similarly the inverse will happen as the thermistor cools down(?)

But then I also don't understand what the purpose of R2 is, unless it's value is set high enough that all the charge coming out of TEMP doesn't just go straight to ground.

I apologise if this is a rookie question, I don't know much about EE and am learning as I go!

[image]

Comment: How to use the TP4056 TEMP control Input ... For R1-R2-NTC explains ... See this https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056-page2.html and also the page1 https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056.html

Comment: @Antonio51 oh wow thanks! I'll have to read them later as I've got to go out, but they look like really great resources. Kind of uncanny how specific to my question they are.